# Most efficient way to reshape tensor into sequences

Tags: tensorflow

I am working with audio in TensorFlow, and would like to obtain a series of sequences which could be obtained from *sliding a window* over my data, so to speak. Examples to illustrate my situation:

**Current Data Format:**

Shape = [batch_size, num_features]

```
example = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
  [10, 11, 12],
  [13, 14, 15]
]
```

**What I want:**

Shape = [batch_size - window_length + 1, window_length, num_features]

```
example = [
  [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
  ],
  [
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [10, 11, 12]
  ],
  [
    [7, 8, 9],
    [10, 11, 12],
    [13, 14, 15]
  ],
]
```

My current solution is to do something like this:

```
list_of_windows_of_data = []
for x in range(batch_size - window_length + 1):
    list_of_windows_of_data.append(tf.slice(data, [x, 0], [window_length,
            num_features]))
windowed_data = tf.squeeze(tf.stack(list_of_windows_of_data, axis=0))
```

And this does the transform. However, it also creates 20,000 operations which slows TensorFlow down a lot when creating a graph. If anyone else has a fun and more efficient way to do this, please do share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using `tf.map_fn` as follows:

```
example = tf.constant([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
  [10, 11, 12],
  [13, 14, 15]
]
)
res = tf.map_fn(lambda i: example[i:i+3], tf.range(example.shape[0]-2), dtype=tf.int32)
sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
res.eval()
```

This prints

```
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9]],

       [[ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15]]])
```

Comment: I finally got around to testing and implementing this. You've cut out all 20,000 of my extra operations while still giving the same output. The TF graph loads almost instantly which is awesome! Interestingly though, this solution almost doubles my current batch processing time. It might be a trade off between letting tensorflow spend a minute set up it's graph, and doing it dynamically. Anyway, awesome and neat solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in [`tf.extract_image_patches`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/extract_image_patches):

```
example = tf.constant([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
  [10, 11, 12],
  [13, 14, 15]
]
)
res = tf.reshape(tf.extract_image_patches(example[None,...,None],
  [1,3,3,1], [1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1], 'VALID'), [-1,3,3])
```